# dismantling LCD screen base

Tags: lcd, repair

I recently picked up this widescreen lcd for a good price except that the base is all gunked up where the parts meet. Before I can really call it mine I would like to take the parts apart and reassemble them after cleaning them thoroughly. I am assuming some of the panels snap together as the point of entry since I do not see any of the bolt heads. And before I just start prying on them I thought of posting my inquiry here. Is anyone familiar with how these screen bases are put together?

[Rear top view of Samsung monitor upright](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x5u9.jpg)

[where upright connects into base, four o'clock view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfNmC.jpg)

[where upright connects into base, eleven o'clock view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2pp2.jpg)

[upside down, ten o'clock view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bETD7.jpg)

Comment: What's the model part number? Should be on the same sticker or plate as the serial number.

Comment: syncmaster 225bw